# Equivalence relation on graphs identifying degrees

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

I consider a connected simple finite graph $G$ and I define the equivalence relation $v\sim w$ on its vertex set such that $v\sim w$ if and only if $\mathrm{deg}(v)=\mathrm{deg}(w)$. I found that it is possible that the quotient graph of $G$ under this equivalence relation may be isomorph to the path graph of length $\delta$ where $\delta$ is the number of distinct degrees in $G$. Ordering the degrees by $d_1<...<d_{\delta}$ the existence of such an isomorphism implies that any vertex of degree $d_i$ in $G$ is only connected to vertices with degree $d_{i\pm 1}$.

But can I say more about $G$? Is there a general class of graphs which satisfies this property?

I am thankful for any input I can get. I am going to use it for Markov chains because I managed to prove that a certain Markov chain is reversible if and only if said isomorphism exists for the hereinbefore defined quotient graph.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing we can do is ask for more structure. Write each $d_i$ as $a_i + b_i$ and ask that each vertex of degree $d_i$ is adjacent to $a_i$ vertices of degree $d_{i-1}$ and $b_i$ vertices of degree $d_{i+1}$. For the first degree $d_1$ we want $a_1 = 0$ and for the last degree $d_k$ we want $b_k = 0$; for the rest, we can choose $a_i$ and $b_i$ arbitrarily, but we want $a_i, b_i > 0$.

Then if there are $n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k$ vertices of degree $d_1 < d_2 < \dots < d_k$ respectively, we must have $n_i b_i = n_{i+1} a_{i+1}$ for the edge counts to work out, and we can do this just by having the proportion $n_1 : n_2 : \dots : n_k$ be right. We should scale up the proportion so that $n_i \ge \max\{b_{i-1}, a_{i+1}\}$ for all $i$, and then constructing the graph is possible...

...we just need a method for constructing a bipartite graph with $n_i$ vertices of degree $b_i$ on one side, and $n_{i+1}$ vertices of degree $a_{i-1}$ on the other side.

Here's one way. Just order the $n_i$ vertices on the first side cyclically. Give the first vertex on the other side edges to the first $a_{i-1}$ of them, then the next vertex edges to the next $a_{i-1}$, and so on, wrapping around when necessary. This will work out in the end. Actually, there are usually many ways to do this.

---

There are probably other graphs we can construct that don't have the regular $d_i = a_i + b_i$ split, but those are harder to find.